# How can I finish this about LTE diagram using filldraw rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is an picture from 3GPP "LTE Resource Guide" called {LTE Uplink Subframe with Normal Cyclic Prefix}

[image]

I have done

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=blue] (4.5,6)rectangle (1,0.5);%PUCCH-ACK/NACK/SRI
\filldraw[fill=orange] (3.5,6) rectangle (0.5,0.5);%PUCCH-CQI
\filldraw[fill=white!50!blue](3,6) rectangle(0.5,0.5);%Demodulation RS
\filldraw[fill=orange] (2.5,6) rectangle (1,0.5);%PUCCH-CQI
\filldraw[fill=orange] (2,6) rectangle (0.5,0.5);%PUCCH-CQI
\filldraw[fill=white!50!blue] (1,6) rectangle (0.5,0.5);%Demodulation RS
\filldraw[fill=white!50!blue] (4,0.5) rectangle (4,0.5);%Demodulation RS
\filldraw[fill=white!50!blue] (0,6) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\filldraw[fill=orange] (0,6) rectangle (0.5,0.5);%PUCCH-CQI
\filldraw[fill=orange] (0,6) rectangle (0.5,0.5);%PUCCH-CQI
\filldraw[fill=black!30!green] (2,0.5) rectangle (5,5.5);%PUSCH-Data
\filldraw[fill=black!30!green] (0,0.5) rectangle (1.5,5.5);%PUSCH-Data
\filldraw[fill=white!50!blue] (2.5,0) rectangle (1,0.5);%Demodulation RS
\filldraw[fill=blue] (3,0) rectangle (1,0.5);%PUCCH-ACK/NACK/SRI
\filldraw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);%PUCCH-ACK/NACK/SRI
\filldraw[fill=white!50!blue] (0,1) rectangle (1.5,5);%Demodulation RS
\draw[step=0.5,thick] (0,0) grid (8,6);%resource grid
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

now my problem is how to add little grid on the right side of this  figure.
maybe you probably have a question about why not use this figure.
my answer is my teacher just accepts painting own
and I just know LaTeX can accept the file eps format

Comment: _I just know LaTeX can accept the file eps format_? Not at all!

Comment: '...you probably have a question about why not use this figure. my answer is my teacher just accepts painting own...'. So is this an assignment for a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for a more "semantic" implementation. Instead of giving apparently arbitrary coordinates and colors, define some styles with names related to your problem, for example:

```
\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {draw=green!20, very thick},
  Data/.style = {cell, fill=black!50!green},
  CQI/.style  = {cell, fill=orange},
  RS/.style   = {cell, fill=blue!50},
  ACK/.style  = {cell, fill=blue!70!black},
}
```

Then, you can give "shorthand" single-char-names to some of these styles, for example:

```
\tikzset{
  !/.style = {Data},
  C/.style = {CQI},
  R/.style = {RS},
  A/.style = {ACK},
}
```

This will allow you to create a `\foreach` loop to draw all your grid, which is then specified as a "matrix" of characters, in which each char represents the style in which the cell has to be drawn:

```
  C,R,C,C,C,R,C,A,A,R,R,R,A,A,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  A,A,R,R,R,A,A,C,R,C,C,C,R,C
```

This is the complete code which uses these ideas:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {draw=green!20, very thick},
  border/.style = {draw=black!50!green, very thick},
  Data/.style = {cell, fill=black!50!green},
  CQI/.style  = {cell, fill=orange},
  RS/.style   = {cell, fill=blue!50},
  ACK/.style  = {cell, fill=blue!70!black},
  % Shorthands
  !/.style = {Data},
  C/.style = {CQI},
  R/.style = {RS},
  A/.style = {ACK},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \cell [count=\i from 0] in {
  C,R,C,C,C,R,C,A,A,R,R,R,A,A,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  A,A,R,R,R,A,A,C,R,C,C,C,R,C} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{mod(\i, 14)}  % 14 is the number of cells per row
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{floor(\i/14)}
    \filldraw[\cell] (\x,-\y) rectangle (\x+1,-\y-1);
  }

\draw[border] 
   ($(0,0)+(-\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle 
   ($(14,-8) + (\pgflinewidth, -\pgflinewidth)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and produces:

[image: Result]

Now for the legend to the right. First, define an appropiate style for the text:

```
\tikzset{
  legend text/.style = {anchor=center, black!50, font=\sffamily},
}
```

Then, you can use `positioning` library to define a coordinate where the first legend will appear. After the above grid was drawn, the node named `current bounding box` represents the rectangle containing that grid, so we can position the leged 2cm to its right with:

```
\coordinate[right=2cm of current bounding box.north east] (legend);
```

And with a loop we draw each little square, put the text legend below, and redefine the coordinate `legend` to be 2cm below of the previous one:

```
\foreach \style/\text in {
   C/{PUCCH-CQI}, 
   A/{PUCCH-ACK/NACK/SRI}, 
   !/{PUSCH-Data},
   R/{Demodulation RS}
} {
  \filldraw[border,\style] (legend) rectangle +(1,-1);
  \node[below=1.3cm of legend, xshift=0.5cm, legend text] {\text};
  \coordinate[below=2cm of legend] (legend);
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

and this is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  cell/.style = {draw=green!20, very thick},
  border/.style = {draw=black!50!green, very thick},
  Data/.style = {cell, fill=black!50!green},
  CQI/.style  = {cell, fill=orange},
  RS/.style   = {cell, fill=blue!50},
  ACK/.style  = {cell, fill=blue!70!black},
  legend text/.style = {anchor=center, black!50, font=\sffamily},
  % Shorthands
  !/.style = {Data},
  C/.style = {CQI},
  R/.style = {RS},
  A/.style = {ACK},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \cell [count=\i from 0] in {
  C,R,C,C,C,R,C,A,A,R,R,R,A,A,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  !,!,!,R,!,!,!,!,!,!,R,!,!,!,
  A,A,R,R,R,A,A,C,R,C,C,C,R,C} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{mod(\i, 14)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{floor(\i/14)}
    \filldraw[\cell] (\x,-\y) rectangle (\x+1,-\y-1);
  }

\draw[border] 
   ($(0,0)+(-\pgflinewidth,\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle 
   ($(14,-8) + (\pgflinewidth, -\pgflinewidth)$);

\coordinate[right=2cm of current bounding box.north east] (legend);

\foreach \style/\text in {
   C/{PUCCH-CQI}, 
   A/{PUCCH-ACK/NACK/SRI}, 
   !/{PUSCH-Data},
   R/{Demodulation RS}
} {
  \filldraw[border,\style] (legend) rectangle +(1,-1);
  \node[below=1.3cm of legend, xshift=0.5cm, legend text] {\text};
  \coordinate[below=2cm of legend] (legend);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: '...you probably have a question about why not use this figure. my answer is my teacher just accepts painting own...'. So is this an assignment for a class?