# Could foreach generating figure have coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I Encounter a problem that is foreach loop generating figure can have coordinate?

this is I asked before [How can I finish this about LTE diagram using filldraw rectangle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184657/how-can-i-finish-this-about-lte-diagram-using-filldraw-rectangle)

now I want put this diagram into a part of my tikz figure, but I don't know how to coordinate it.

please help me!

Or I only have to use orringe method to complete my figure...(using draw grid)

Comment: One page 1038 of the manual it mentions a local bounding box.

Comment: '...you probably have a question about why not use this figure. my answer is my teacher just accepts painting own...'. So is this an assignment for a class?

Comment: In fact, there seem to be several questions you've asked of this kind. If your teaching wants you to create your own, then you cannot ask people here to do the work for you. The teacher wants to see what **you** can do - not the collective efforts of TeX.SE. If this is homework or coursework, you ought not turn the code you've been given here as if it were your own. Do note that **code published here may only be legally used with attribution**. But the larger issue is that you need to do the work yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You place your thingy from other question in a scope and shift it around via

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Your main picture

\begin{scope}[shift={(<xcoord>,<ycoord>)}] % Change these coordinates to your needs
%<code from your other question wwithout the \begin{tikzpicture},\end{tikzpicture}>
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

We always want to help you but please you also help us by formulating your questions better. It starts not to be fun anymore if it goes like this for a while.

Comment: let me try it for a moment